# Detecting if a COM port has closed

Tags: c, winapi, serial-port

I am reading a Bluetooth COM port, getting data from a microcontroller.
After initializing the port, I am using this to read the port:

```
while(1)
if(WaitCommEvent(com_hnd, &dwEventMask, NULL))
```

This works fine, but if I close the COM port, the program will wait forever in this loop, without detecting the fact that the COM port is gone (I have an else for that if(), where I check for errors).

How can I check and see if it still open?

Comment: IIRC, Make sure you set a time out with [SetCommTimeOuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363437(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Well, that's sloppy.  Drivers that emulate COM ports are often flaky.  You can partially solve it by using the 3rd argument, allowing you to use WaitForMultipleObjects() so you can also break the wait with an event.  But then re-opening the port could be pretty perilous.  Better look for a driver update first.

Comment: One thing I can do is wait to see if there is no data coming for a certain period. The communication with the microcontroller should happen at predetermined intervals. If no data is coming, then probably the connection was lost. But I was hoping for something more flexible..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already suggested in comments, you will probably want some external way to stop the waiting, like an event + WaitForMultipleObjects(). You can also wait for the actual COM port handle obtained from CreateFile.

Do you actually need to use WaitCommEvent? As far as I know, you should only need that function if you are using handshaking signals and other such oddities. You can use ReadFile if you are only interested in the data. In my experience, that function is more reliable.

I have worked with similar COM port devices and the most robust way to spot that they have been disconnected seems to be checking the result of ReadFile:

```
BOOL result;

result = ReadFile(...);

if(result == FALSE)
{
  DWORD last_error = GetLastError();
  if(last_error == ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED)  // disconnected ?
  {
    close();                                 // close the port
  }
}
```

I'm of course not sure whether or not this will work in your specific case, but I'm using this method in some production code that has ended up with multiple crappy USB-to-serial adapters.

Comment: Actually, I am using ReadFile() inside that WaitCommEvent(), and I do have an error check at ReadFile() too, and no errors are detected :/

Comment: I tried ReadFile() without WaitCommEvent(), still no change :/ It waits forever...

Comment: Ok, actually it worked, ReadFile() by itself will return after a while if nothing is read. Thanks!

Comment: @Radu I don't remember all details, but I believe ReadFile returns after the time specified by SetCommTimeOuts().

Comment: Yes, it did, that was the trick :) I was expecting it to return an error.